# Difference between fgets - array vs pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have read articles about the difference of array and a pointer, but I am still not sure if it's affect in anyway if I would like to use scanf/fgets.

Let's say I've got a 2 functions which read words.

```
void read1() {
    char *text;
    text = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
    fgets(text, 50, stdin);
}

void read2() {
    char text[50];
    fgets(text, 50, stdin);
}
```

Is there any difference between this codes?

Comment: In the second case, the input array ends it life when you exit the function. In the first case, you can return the pointer.

Comment: You **did** notice one has to use `malloc`? Not clear what you ask.

Comment: What kind of "difference"? Your "codes" have identical observable behavior. (And they essentially do nothing useful.)  Are two pieces of code with identical observable behavior (which basically do nothing) really different?

Comment: @AnT Yea I would add more code, but why? Pointers and arrays differ in some ways and I wanted to know if during execution of this two "codes" (as you have said) there are going to be any other changes in a memory.

Comment: @Kubekk: Modern compilers can often recognize and optimize pieces of code that have identical observable behavior, even if they use completely different memory allocation mechanisms. Modern compilers are pretty good as discarding any "useless" code that does not contribute to observable behavior of the program. Which means that theoretically both of your pieces of code can easily end up being translated into the same code. No difference at all.

Comment: @AnT: There very well is different observable behaviour, considering `malloc` has side-effects. The compiler shall not modify it that way (it would also interfere with testing/debugging mechanisms which use a modified `malloc` or a wrapper which does additional operations.

Comment: As far as the `fgets` call itself is concerned, there's no difference - it sees a `char *` as its first argument either way (the array expression in the second call is converted to a pointer expression before being passed to `fgets`).  Where it matters is how you manage the input buffer *after* you've read data into it.  If it needs to hang around after the function exits, then you need to use dynamic memory (or pass the target buffer as a parameter to the `readN` function).  This means you also need to manually `free` that buffer when you're done with it.

Comment: @Olaf: That's all implementation details that might not exist at all. In general, "having side effects" is not defined as "observable behavior". It all depends on the exact nature of these side effects. And we don't know these details. Compilers might have full knowledge of `malloc` semantics and conclude that in this case the call can be eliminated.

Comment: @AnT: Yes, it is implementation details. But it is also fact for any hosted environment with a full-size OS. With side-effects I mean of course "beyond the visibility of the compiler". Maybe I better had used "external effects". That would not be the first time a compiler makes too many assumptions.

Comment: @Olaf: The compiler is free to assume that no side effects exist besides those mandated by the language spec. It is easy to verify that GCC will freely and immediately discard any "unused" calls to `malloc`. The only thing that can save the call to `malloc`in this example is actually the fact that the buffer is passed to `fgets`. `fgets` is observable and has to be preserved. And the compiler does not have a buffer-less replacement for `fgets` at its disposal.

Comment: @AnT: `malloc` typically has side-effects outside the TU. Not only that it resides in a different TU, but also it calls OS functions which have side-effects. This becomes worse with dynamic linking, i.e. the side-effects can only be determined at run-time. Interesting discussion, but it leads too far for comments and I don't have the time for this right now. I undetstand it is not satisfying, but I'll leave it at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Large part of the convenience that comes with writing functions that take pointers is that they do not care about the memory location, as long as the memory pointed to by the pointer satisfies function's sizing requirements.

In particular, `fgets` makes no difference between the two calls: it cares only that the pointer `ptr` that you pass to it be valid for writing `length` characters.

Even though there is no difference to `fgets`, your code may care very much about the location of the pointer in memory: for example, your first code snippet must `free(text)` in order to avoid a memory leak. In contrast, your second code snippet does not need to free `test`. However, `text` in the first function remains valid even when function's scope is over, and can be returned to the caller if the function's return type is appropriately changed. The second function cannot do that without making a copy, because `text` goes out of scope as soon as the end of the function is reached.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, the first snippet does not have a success check for `malloc()` so it has the possibility of invoking UB by dereferencing a NULL pointer, `malloc()` failure case. Also, this faces a risk of [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) as you neither `free()` the pointer there nor return it to the caller to make calling `free()` possible at a later point.

Otherwise, in ***this particular*** case, there's not much difference from the *"array and a pointer" point of view* , anyway as long as both of them (passed to `fgets()`) point to valid memory chunk of the specified size.

To elaborate, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [....]

So, for the snippet using `char text[50];`, the call

```
fgets(text, 50, stdin);
```

makes the first argument to be a pointer to the first element of an array of 50 `char`s which is behaviorally similar to passing a pointer to a chunk of memory of size of 50 `char`s.

Comment: What would have happend if there would be No enough memory to allocate it for array? I mean while using malloc there is a possibility to check if there was not NULL returned. What about array?

Comment: automatic allocation are guaranteed, no need to check for that. :)

Comment: Nit-pick: from the `fgets` view there is absolutely no difference, because it get a psointer for both cases.

Comment: @Olaf Right sir, I added that related quote also. Any changes in wordings suggested?

Comment: @SouravGhosh "automatic allocation are guaranteed" - That's a bit problematic, because typical  implementations only have a limited amount of memory for automatic variables (notice me avoiding the word "stack";.-). (oh, and: happy new year!)

Comment: @Olaf Happy new year to you too sir. So how do you propose to modify the wordings there? I know it sounds a bit _off_, any better alternatives?

Comment: Well, dear sir, I would leave it as-is. Just because we are here at the abstract machine, not implementation. I use the "nit-pick" term typically when I don't expect a change. Call it my engineer-gene. :-) To be honest, I don't understand the question. OP should have noticed one snippet requires `malloc`. And a full explanation would be off-topic. It should be part of his C book.

Comment: @Olaf Then I guess it's okay. OK, late now, need to rush for dinner, see you tomorrow, good night. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about the difference between passing arrays and pointers as function arguments and declaring function parameters like arrays and pointers.

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object** and is not an lvalue. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undeﬁned.

And on the other hand (6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes))

> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted
>   to ‘‘qualiﬁed pointer to type’’, where the type qualiﬁers (if any) are
>   those speciﬁed within the [ and ] of the array type derivation...

Thus in this function example

```
void read2() {
    char text[50];
    fgets(text, 50, stdin);
}
```

the array `text` is implicitly converted to pointer of type `char *` that points to the first element of the array. That is the function deals with a pointer. It is not important whether a pointer points to the first element of an array with the automatic storage duration or to the first element of an array with the dynamic storage duration.

And moreover for example these functions declare the same one function

```
void f( char s[50] );
void f( char s[1] );
void f( char s[] );
void f( char *s );
```

because the parameter is adjusted to pointer.

Comment: A good compiler might add options for static code-analysis (as do some tools) and use the array-length as helpful information. So, while strictly not used, it is a good idea to use corect bounds - if not for anything else than documentation purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: In those examples it won't make a difference, but you should free (https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) the one you created via malloc before returning.

Long (and somewhat simplified) answer:

The simplified explanation would be that for fgets both variables named text are pointers. Pointers, as the name suggest point to something, in the case of C, they point to a memory area.

In your first example, the memory area you are pointing to is on the Heap, it is dynamically allocated, it has global scope (you could return this variable, you could set it to a global pointer and use it at any point of your code and you could pass it to another function) and you are responsible to free it (in your code, you didn't which results in a memory leak (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

In your second example, the memory area you are pointing to is on the stack (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) which is a memory area created when your program starts and that is used to hold variables (as well as some other values for function calls and static variables that I won't discuss in this answer). The scope of this variable is the current function and any function you call from it, but when you return from read2 the content will be overwritten in time, hence you must not return this value or set it to a global pointer, otherwise you will run into trouble later.

Comment: Strictly, the pointer returned by `malloc()` has no name and hence no scope, but it does have allocated lifetime (which means until deallocated or the program ends).  Double check my terminology — I've not reread that but of the standard so far this year.  But the concept is about right.

Answer (score -2):

- `fgets()` take `char*` as input argument and `char text[50]` when passed to `fegts` becomes converted to `char*` to first element of the array. And `text` in `read1()` is already a  `char*`. So `fgets()` invocation is same.
- Difference is `text` in `read1()` being dynamically allocated is alive even when the control reaches `}` of function  `read1()`. To free it **during program execution** you have to call `free()` explicitly.
- The `text` in `main()`, being an automatic variable as soon as control reaches `}` of `read2()` or the scope of `read2()` **ends** it becomes and free and you can't access it further. (If you try to do so then you have [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

Comment: There is no stack in the code. The standard does not require using a stack for _automatic_ variables. Don't mix language abstraction and implementation. And the array does not end when the scope is left. You can pass a pointer to it to a function without problems.

Comment: @Olaf.: When you call a function including main() a activation frame is pushed in the memory which behaves as FIFO in nature (that's why stack) and it is generic irrespective of Language implemenattion.

Comment: If you show me a quote from the standard where this is actually said for the abstract machine, I (and @Olaf probably too) will believe you. Point is, frames or stacks are not defined by the standard. There are automatic variables, which can be implemented using a stack due to their properties.

Comment: Please provide a reference to where the C standard mandates using a stack for automatic variables. FYI: there are implementations which do not use a stack (they might use one optionally if you use recursion).

Comment: @Downvoter: I actually would doubt the source of that reference. Simply because the official standard does not have such a requirement ;-)

Comment: @Olaf.: Two things then..if possible suggest me an edit 2) If they don't use stack or anything similar how do they do? **Downvoter**

Comment: @coderredoc: 1) Read the standard. 2) Learn about compiler construction. 3) See some embedded compilers and/or 4) Search what "statica call tree" means (meditate why I excluded recursion, which is never required and often not used anyway).

Comment: @Olaf.: I dont know about the 3) and 4) ...I dont know what to say..as if I dont know anything. I read a bit about first two..more on 2)..I would ask you to write an answer saying what I said...in correct way. I will delete my answer. Thanks..

Comment: See the other answers; no need for another.

Comment: Let alone you don't have to reason why you argument at the same abstraction level OP asks, please re-read my comments. I had other issues which are not fixed.

Comment: @Olaf.: what other issues? Yo have said abt one thing that I corrected

Comment: I don't like to repreat myself. **Read** my very first comment!

Comment: @Olaf.: Please Check my answer....I have disturbed you a lot of times. Sorry for that.

Comment: Really I don't understand this site...the more effort I put to make the answer more readable and accurate it is discouraged.

Comment: @coderredoc: I removed my DV, as you corrected the major errors. Sorry to tell it still is not a good answer imo, because it describes things way more complicated than necessary. I will not check it again, but as general advice, it is a good idea to stay at the abstraction level the question has (or use the most appropriate, because askers often jump betewwn abstractions themselves). It is also helpful if you use the standard's nomenclature which is (mostly) well defined and accepted.